# How to write the html content in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I need to add images dynamically to this div through jQuery.By calling the `ajax` I am getting the images from the sever side, just i need to add like this below code it  is there in HTML, I need to write the same code in jQuery to add images dynamically.

JSP code:

```
<div class="sortable">
<div class="box span5" style="margin-left: 20px;">
<div class="box-header well" >
<h2><i class="icon-th"></i>Section </h2>
<div class="box-icon">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-minimize btn-round"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="box-content"  style="height:230px;" > 
<img border="0" src="img/paichart1.png" alt="Pulpit rock" width="370" height="240" >
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery code to call `ajax`:

```
function studentatt() {
    alert(12);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'dashbord.do?method=getGrade',
        success: function(Jsonresponce) {
            $.each(Jsonresponce, function(index, value) {
            });
        }
    });

    $("#studentatt").dialog("open");
}
```

[image]

Comment: json = [{"secId":0,"secName":"A","gradeName":0,"mentor":0,"imagename":"Apaichart.png"},{"secId":0,"secName":"B","gradeName":0,"mentor":0,"imagename":"Bpaichart.png"},{"secId":0,"secName":"C","gradeName":0,"mentor":0,"imagename":"Cpaichart.png"}]

Comment: That is myjson content that cotince there images i need to disply those images.

Comment: Just I want to write the same code in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside ajax function

```
var img = $('<img id="dynamic">'); //Equivalent: $(document.createElement('img'))
img.attr('src', value);
img.appendTo('#imagediv');
```

value should contain image url

Add id to div tag

```
<div class="box-content"  style="height:230px;" id="imagediv">
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the attribute of image like following

```
 $('#picture').attr('src', 'https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScY2K5EiTo3WPkagHP4JLQyNtCa0VcVTbr_1f_KbD5gqTp3cCRCqtQaaBLRQ');
```